# Add remote SVN repository for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, svn

I installed the plugin, but couldn't find anything in the documentation for the VS Code SVN plugin.  I'm just looking to point it to a remote svn repository.  Thanks.

Comment: What plug-in did you install? Are you referring to this plug-in? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnstoncode.svn-scm

Comment: Yes, SVN by Chris Johnson.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the [SVN-scm plug-in](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnstoncode.svn-scm), you can check out a working copy using the `SVN: Checkout` command in the Command Palette.

[image: SVN: Checkout]